# Android Get device admin permission without user action for lock unlock screen progremmatically

Tags: android, permissions, admin, lockscreen

I want to lock the android device screen like when the user click the power button.
I can turn the screen on so the user will unlock the screen but can't "lock"/turn off the screen without the admin permission that the user should accept manually..

I have custom ROM so if anyone know how to grant admin permission to my app without asking the user it will be great!